Deserialize Json Array String in ASNA AVR
I have this JSON array in string form from where i serialize early in the API call (done in C#). I need to Deserialize it but I keep getting an error Cannot deserialize the JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type ' ' because type requires JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
I just need to figure out how to get the array of objects back into JSON form so I can pick out what i need in the code.
I know this has been asked but I need a solution in ASNA AVR, not C# or javascript or any other language
[
  {
    "coverageType": "JAYGO",
    "parts": [
      {
        "partNumber": "25FR102",
        "unitsOrdered": "2"
      },
      {
        "partNumber": "25FR103",
        "unitsOrdered": "2"
      },
      {
        "partNumber": "25SV105",
        "unitsOrdered": "8"
      },
      {
        "partNumber": "25WR104",
        "unitsOrdered": "2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "coverageType": "PAMMO",
    "parts": [
      {
        "partNumber": "25SV104",
        "unitsOrdered": "1"
      },
      {
        "partNumber": "25SV124",
        "unitsOrdered": "10"
      },
      {
        "partNumber": "25SV126",
        "unitsOrdered": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
]

BegClass PartsDefinition
    DclProp coverageType    Type( *String ) Access( *Public )
    DclProp parts           Type( Parts ) Access( *Public )

    BegConstructor Access( *Public )
        *This.parts = *New Parts()
    EndConstructor
EndClass

BegClass Parts
    DclProp partNumber      Type( *String ) Access( *Public )
    DclProp unitsOrdered    Type( *String ) Access( *Public )
EndClass


DclFld PartsObject      Type ( PartsDefinition )

PartsObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( PartsString, *TypeOf( PartsDefinition )) *As PartsDefinition

